# phpseclib Include breaking echo

Tags: php, phpseclib

When I include phpseclib files my echo stops working. I had a hard time installing phpseclib the 'right' way, so I'm hosting it on the website directory and including from there.

Any guidance as to why echo is no longer working would be appreciated. I don't get any errors either.

```
<?php


include("http://website.com/folder/phpseclib1.0.2/Net/SSH2.php");
set_include_path('http://website.com/folder/phpseclib1.0.2');

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('000.000.000.000');

if (!$ssh->login('user', 'pass')) {
        exit('Login Failed');
        }

echo $ssh->exec('cd /home/cpaneluser/public_html/folder');
echo $ssh->exec('openssl smime -sign -signer newcertificate.pem -inkey key.pem -nodetach -outform der -in unsigned.txt -out signed.txt');
echo $ssh->exec('chmod user:user signed.txt');
echo $ssh->read();

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($ssh);
echo '</pre>';

?>
```

Comment: You can't `set_include_path` to a remote URL, only a local path. And typically you want to _append_ to your include path. You need to get phpseclib on your local machine.

Comment: I dont know whats wrong but it hasn't 'broken' echo!

Comment: You're doing `$ssh->read()`. You're supposed to pass a string that you're expecting back into it. If you don't it'll just hang until it times out (which it does in 10 seconds). Typically you'd pass the prompt to `$ssh->read()` but in your case I don't think you should be using it at all (see my answer for more info).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just put phpseclib in /var/lib/php/phpseclib or something and then do `set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . '/var/lib/php/phpseclib');`. Or you could install it with Composer.

Anyway, installation aside...

```
echo $ssh->exec('cd /home/cpaneluser/public_html/folder');
echo $ssh->exec('openssl smime -sign -signer newcertificate.pem -inkey key.pem -nodetach -outform der -in unsigned.txt -out signed.txt');
echo $ssh->exec('chmod user:user signed.txt');
echo $ssh->read();
```

That won't work. You'll change directories all right but then when you run the openssl command you'll be right back in the starting directory - not the directory you cd'd into. See http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ssh/examples.html#chdir for an explanation as to why. And `$ssh->read()` only does anything if you use it with an interactive shell (eg. you've done `$ssh->write()`) or if you've [enabled a PTY](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ssh/pty.html). My recommendation: do this:

```
$commands = [];
$command[] = 'cd /home/cpaneluser/public_html/folder';
$command[] = 'openssl smime -sign -signer newcertificate.pem -inkey key.pem -nodetach -outform der -in unsigned.txt -out signed.txt';
$command[] = 'chmod user:user signed.txt';
echo $ssh->exec(implode('; ', $command));
```